# Azure SQL DW COPY Command fails with syntax error

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-synapse

When I run the example command from the documentation page, it fails with syntax error. Any idea why it is failing and what is the correct syntax?

Doc page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/copy-into-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest

Query: `COPY INTO dbo.[lineitem] FROM 'https://unsecureaccount.blob.core.windows.net/customerdatasets/folder1/lineitem.csv’`

Error:

> Parse error at line: 2, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'COPY'. [SQL State=S0001, DB Errorcode=103010]

Comment: The docs say it's in public preview at the moment so I guess you either have to sign up for it, or it's only available in Azure Synapse resources created recently?

Comment: Hi kiran,  If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested and the COPY INTO also doesn't work in my ADW.

My Azure SQL Data warehouse is in EastUS  region.

I asked Azure SQL support for help, they replied me:
[image]

This is caused by the COPY INTO feature is still blocked on your ADW resgion.

I'm now asking the list of the regions which  the COPY INTO feature is still blocked now. You can wait my update.

Hope this helps.